# mysql empty result if the query contain dash

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin

When i try to delete some rows from MY-SQL DB using the following query i get empty results:

```
DELETE FROM custom_prices WHERE day IN (2018-04-01,2018-04-02,2018-04-03)
```

The problem that MY-SQL server add spaces before any "-" .... the query become like this:

```
DELETE FROM custom_prices WHERE day IN ( 2018 -04 -01, 2018 -04 -02, 2018 -04 -03 )
```

The day column is DATE type ... i tried to change the type to string but still give me empty results...
any body can help ?

Comment: `-` is a minus. And you need to enclose dates in __quotes__

Comment: @u_mulder if this solves the problem then please write it as an answer.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using `day` as a column name.  There is a function in MySQL  `WHERE DAY(date_fld) = 1` for example.  MySql might be smart enough to figure this out without backtics, but I'm not a fan of it.  Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your date in quotes like below:

```
DELETE FROM custom_prices WHERE day IN ('2018-04-01','2018-04-02','2018-04-03')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query has issue. You need to put values in quotes.

```
DELETE FROM custom_prices WHERE day IN ('2018-04-01','2018-04-02','2018-04-03')
```

Comment: Maybe `day` should be converted to correct format first?

Comment: `'2018-04-01','2018-04-02','2018-04-03'` are valid dates (as per mysql date formate) yyyy-mm-dd. Doesn't it? @u_mulder